# null check operator used on a null value in flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f11S.png)

```
 class News {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? imageUrl;
}


return Container(
  child: Center(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Image.network(_featuredNews.imageUrl!),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  _featuredNews.title!,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
```

When I run this code Null check operator is used on a null value my flutter 3.0 please help me with what I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe _featuredNews.imageUrl! or _featuredNews.title! is the reason.

What about you try

1. use `errorBuilder` in Image.network
2. or change to like `_featuredNews.title ?? ''`  to handle
3. or receive the variables by 'required' variables
   .
   .
   .

Comment: can you show me sample or example

Comment: @IrfanTariq 
1.  ```Text(_featuredNews.title ?? '')```

2. ```Image.network(url, errorBuilder: ((context, error, stackTrace)  {return Image.asset(assetImage)}),);```

simple example. just search like "Image.network errorbuilder example"

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses Dart language. Please refer to [Dart - Null Aware Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-null-aware-operators/).

Add this

```
_featuredNews.title ?? ""

_featuredNews.imageUrl ?? ""
```

Comment: Flutter uses Dart language; check the Null aware operators in Dart. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-null-aware-operators/#:~:text=Null%2Daware%20operators%20in%20dart,instead%20of%20throwing%20an%20error.

Comment: but sometimes the api request may fail due to many reasons so he can put an error image result to show instead of just "" correct me if I am wrong